# Is there an automated installer/manager for mod_wsgi 3.4?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi

```
# yum --showduplicates list mod_wsgi | expand
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.cov.ukservers.com
 * epel: mirrors.coreix.net
 * extras: centos.serverspace.co.uk
 * updates: mirror.cov.ukservers.com
Available Packages
mod_wsgi.x86_64                          3.2-7.el6                          base
```

Does anyone know if there's a package manager that has mod_wsgi in version 3.4? I've been trying to get mod_wsgi working for Python 2.7 instead of the default 2.6 but I've been having troubles doing it manually. There must be a manager out there with version 3.4 in it.

Comment: You don't need a package manager, but a repo that might contain such a package for RHEL/CentOS 6. But there is no such thing according to pkgs.org.